# CSRF token mismatch in post request in 3.6 version

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, csrf

I have two different apps of cakephp. One has a version 3.5 and other 3.6.

When i used and built 3.5 app i did not have a problem of `CSRF matching in post request.` But now as i am using 3.6 it is giving me error of CSRF token.

Although in both app's `AppController`, CSRF component is disable.

`//$this->loadComponent('Csrf');`

i am using simple post request like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../user/my_action",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            set_data(data.response);
        }
    });
```

What am i missing? or some configuration i have done wrong?

Comment: Try to remove your cookies and cache.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The latest 3.6 application template now uses the CSRF middleware by default, see your apps `src/Application.php` file. Unfortunately this change hasn't been documented properly, and hit people by surprise.

Ideally you do not disable it, but instead pass the proper CSRF token alongside with your AJAX requests, you can easily obtain the token from the request object in your view templates, for example in the layout to make it globally available:

```
<script>
var csrfToken = <?= json_encode($this->request->getParam('_csrfToken')) ?>;
// ...
</script>
```

You can then easily use it in your AJAX requests:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
    },
    // ...
});
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Middleware >  Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-middleware)**
- **[Cookbook > Middleware > CSRF Protection and AJAX Requests](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/middleware.html#csrf-protection-and-ajax-requests)**

Comment: ndm sorry for late, your solution works very well. problem i am getting is ajax url. due to change in the ajax post requests i think they have also changed how the url is made in ajax.

Comment: it did not append the site url automatically while i was using 3.5 cake. ../controller/action was workign fine. it have to do something with csrf ??

Comment: @fatpotato No, what the URLs need to look like has nothing to do with CSRF protection. You should use [**`Router::url()`**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#generating-urls) or [**the URL helper**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html) (requires disabling escaping when used for JS) to build proper root relative URLs.

Comment: i should pass this url to the ctp file and then catch it in the js file?

Comment: @fatpotato Just like you'd do it with the token, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Add this code on your $.ajax() function call:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) { // Add this line
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val());
 },  // Add this line
```

Answer (score 2):

For **CakePHP 3.8**, this worked for me. In **config\routes.php**
comment the line as so :

```
//$routes->applyMiddleware('csrf');
```

Comment: Thanks for answer . Although this is another approach but you should not disable it. as this is the basic and major security measure.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same error, without using ajax, the problem was that admin theme was not using cakephp 3 form helper sintax, it was html.

after i changed  with Form->create() ?> Form->end() ?> it worked fine

Comment: work for me, but needs in $.ajax call:
 beforeSend: function (xhr) { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val());
        },