# CakePHP 3.6.10 disable completely CSRF token check

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I need to completely disable the control of the CSRF token for my application.
I tried to use:

```
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
      $this->getEventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
    }
```

In AppController but it does not seem to work.
Manual link: [Disabling the CSRF Component for Specific Actions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html#disabling-the-csrf-component-for-specific-actions)

I did a lot of tests, read many posts but I could not solve.

Ty.

@omerowitz
This is my AppController before filter action:

```
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->getEventManager()->off($this->Security);
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->getEventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
    }
    $this->Auth->allow(['index', 'view', 'display']);
}
```

but it still does not work, I still have the error 'CSRF token mismatch.' when I effect a request with postman

SOLUTION:

I have remove this :

```
->add(new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
     'httpOnly' => true
  ]));
```

From Application.php. 
Why this is not indicated in the manual?

Ty all!

Comment: Are you externally calling an action from postman?

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion) - thanks! I think you'll find that the exception isn't triggered by the component, but [**by the middleware**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916680/csrf-token-mismatch-in-post-request-in-3-6-version/51916959).

Comment: Yes, i call action with postman. This is the stack trace error [click](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/VRDZph5QYS/)

Comment: now I'm using the HTTP protocol, could it be a problem?

Comment: @DanieleCancani Maybe you are sending a `PUT` request, so just remove the condition: `if($this->request->is('post')) {`.

Comment: @DanieleCancani Also check your `AppController` and it's `initialize()` method if it contains this call: `$this->loadComponent('Csrf');` - remove it and it should work. If you load `Security` component like that, try without it and see what happends. I personally never load `Security` in `AppController->initialize`.

Comment: @omerowitz The request is definitely in POST. I've already tried to remove the IF but it still does not work :(  this is my initializ() in appController [click](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/K5hQd4j5rT/)

Comment: Take a close look at the stacktrace, [**as suspected**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147836/cakephp-3-6-10-disable-completely-csrf-token-check#comment91247901_52147836) it's the middleware, not the component.

Comment: @ndm can you tell me how to fix this? thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think in Cake 3.6 You should remove `CsrfProtectionMiddleware` from middleware queue:
`src/Application.php`

Comment: Perfect this work for me ! See first post for detail.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to disable `Security` component. I use this for my API controllers:

```
$this->getEventManager()->off($this->Security);

if($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->getEventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
}
```

I disable it only for POST requests, although disabling both `Security` and `Csrf` will work as well.

---

**Edit:** I put it in my `AppController`, although it will work per-controller.

Security component seems to enable CSRF and Form Tampering.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html

Comment: @amerowitz please watch main post, ty.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
  $this->getEventManager()->makeMess($this->Csrf);
}
```

It's working for me!

You also try with Python Language or Symfony 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

//Src/Application.php

```
public function middleware($middlewareQueue)
{
    $middlewareQueue
        // Catch any exceptions in the lower layers,
        // and make an error page/response
        ->add(ErrorHandlerMiddleware::class)

        // Handle plugin/theme assets like CakePHP normally does.
        ->add(new AssetMiddleware([
            'cacheTime' => Configure::read('Asset.cacheTime')
        ]))

        // Add routing middleware.
        // Routes collection cache enabled by default, to disable route caching
        // pass null as cacheConfig, example: `new RoutingMiddleware($this)`
        // you might want to disable this cache in case your routing is extremely simple
        ->add(new RoutingMiddleware($this, '_cake_routes_'));

        // Add csrf middleware.
        //Comment following Code.
       /* ->add(new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
            'httpOnly' => true
        ]));*/

    return $middlewareQueue;
}
```

//Your perticular controller in my case
//UsersController :

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('admin');
    $this->getEventManager()->off($this->Security);        
}
```

// for initialize method

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Security');
}
```

Try this It's working...

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 3.6.10:

1. go to  src/Application.php
2. Search function **middleware**
3. Comment the below line:

   ->add(new CsrfProtectionMiddleware([
           'httpOnly' => true
        ]));

This would completely disable CSRF token check.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `whitelistCallback` for special prefix or action array

```php
// in src/Application.php
use Cake\Http\Middleware\CsrfProtectionMiddleware;

public function middleware($middlewareQueue) {
    $csrf = new CsrfProtectionMiddleware();

    // Token check will be skipped when callback returns `true`.
    $csrf->whitelistCallback(function ($request) {
        // Skip token check for API URLs.
        if ($request->getParam('prefix') === 'api') {
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Ensure routing middleware is added to the queue before CSRF protection middleware.
    $middlewareQueue->add($csrf);

    return $middlewareQueue;
}
```