# cakephp CSRF token Bypass

Tags: php, cakephp, csrf, csrf-token

I am very new to PHP and having little knowledge about cakePHP

I am trying to pass some sensitive information using POST method from `site1.com` to `site2.com`.

But the Problem is with CSRF protection at `site2.com`, it shows CSRF token Mismatch whenever i tried to pass post parameter to `site2.com` from `site1.com`.

I wanted to know how to bypass this csrf protection.. Is there any way to bypass only for this specific post parameter or domain? or Is there anyway to generate token at `site1.com` and verify at `site2.com` using get method?

Comment: Why do you enable csrf protection and then try to backdoor it?
Thats a security issue. It makes no sense to enable a feature and then back door it.

Comment: If there were a method to generate a token on site1 to work on site2, it would defeat the purpose of CSRF protection since CSRF protection is specifically to _prevent_ cross-site requests. If you don't need it, then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **CsrfProtectionMiddleware** from middleware queue: **src/Application.php**

Answered here [CakePHP 3.6.10 disable completely CSRF token check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147836/cakephp-3-6-10-disable-completely-csrf-token-check/52151741#52151741)