# Cakephp 3.6 - Auth Component on server without mod_rewrite

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem with authentification to my cakephp 3.6 project on the productive server.

The server does not have mod_rewrite active, therefore I followed the instructions on https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html (section "I Can’t Use URL Rewriting") and everything works properly except authentification.

For authentification I basically followed the tutorial on https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html. On my development system (xampp) the authentification is working, but on my productive server I always get the following message after I click the login button:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqtBJ.png)

I already tried the suggested solution from [CSRF token mismatch in post request in 3.6 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916680/csrf-token-mismatch-in-post-request-in-3-6-version?noredirect=1&lq=1) without success.

Thanks and best regards

JS

Comment: First, pls ensure your document root points to your webroot folder `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/webroot` and Also you should enable `AllowOverride All` for this folder too.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I can set this configuration in the 'httpd.conf' of the server, correct?

Comment: I can't see the whole picture of your problem. My point is you should try this option too :)